# On parsing a json schema with mulitple references under anyOf property, only one reference(last one) is returned in the output

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I have a valid json schema which is as below

```
 {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "$id": "abcd",
      "title": "test schema",
      "description": "............",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "a": {
           ...........
           ...........
          },
         "b": {
          .........
          ........
          .........
          },
         "c": {
          ...........
          ..........
          },
         "d": {
          ...........
          ..........
          }
       },
    "anyOf": [
        {
        "type": "object",
              "$ref": "#/properties/a",
              "$ref": "#/properties/b"
        },
            {
             "type": "object",
              "$ref": "#/properties/c",
              "$ref": "#/properties/d"
            }
        ]

    }
```

The schema above is stored in a file and I'm loading this for parsing which can be seen below

```
JSchema schema =
    JSchema.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Backups\testschema.json"));
```

So when I look at the output of schema it is as below

```
My Json Schema
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "abcd",
  "title": "test schema",
  "description": "............",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "a": {
       ...........
       ...........
      },
     "b": {
      .........
      ........
      .........
      },
     "c": {
      ...........
      ..........
      },
     "d": {
      ...........
      ..........
      }
   },
"anyOf": [
    {
          "$ref": "#/properties/b"
    },
        {
          "$ref": "#/properties/d"
        }
    ]

}

I'm wondering why I'm getting only the last reference under the anyOf property

On parsing shouldn't the output be the same as that in the file?
Am I missing something?
My desired output under anyOf is 

"anyOf": [
    {
    "type": "object",
          "$ref": "#/properties/a",
          "$ref": "#/properties/b"
    },
        {
         "type": "object",
          "$ref": "#/properties/c",
          "$ref": "#/properties/d"
        }
    ]
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Json, each object can only have a particular key once. So within one object, you can only have one key with the name `$ref`. The Json that you posted above is invalid; it's up to the implementation what it does - ideally it should throw an error but in this case it looks like the second one is overwriting the first one.

Note that with a `$ref`, the other properties are ignored, so there is little point in using another keyword like `type` in addition to the `$ref`.

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like what you're trying to achieve is to say that either properties "a" and "b" should be present, or properties "c" and "d" should be present.

You can achieve that by replacing the `anyOf` clause with:

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "required": ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
        "required": ["c", "d"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Perfect.
Thanks @Erwin Bolwidt, That was exactly what I was looking for